# Partial derivatives math problem?

Tags: derivatives

I have the function $u=\ln(1+x+y^2-z^2)$. I have to find the value of the expression $u'(x) +u'(y) +u'(z)$ for $z=y=x=1$. In a usual case, I keep one of the variables constant, how do I keep two here?

Comment: In doing a partial, all other vars are constant. The notation for partial w.r.t. $x$ is usually $\partial/\partial x$, not $u'(x)$ -- the "prime" notation is usually for derivative in the one variable case.

Comment: Let $a\in \Bbb R$. You know how to find the derivative of $x\mapsto \ln(1+x+a^2)$, right? Now take $a\in \Bbb R,b\in \Bbb R$. You still know how to find the derivative of $x\mapsto \ln(1+x+a^2-b^2)$, right? Well you're asked to exactly that. *All* the variables except the one with respect to which you want to find the partial derivative are arbitrary *constants* that you can think of as chosen before defining your function.

Comment: Instead of considering $(x,y,z)\mapsto \ln(1+x+y^2-z^2)$, you consider $y,z\in \Bbb R$ and $x\mapsto \ln(1+x+y^2-z^2)$

Answer (score 1):

For example with the partial derivative with respect to $x$ just write $$u = \ln((1+y^2-z^2)+x).$$ Then treat $(1+y^2-z^2)$ as a constant.

Comment: @Tweetingbird I think Joe is right there must be a mistake in your book.

Answer (score 0):

Treat both variable as one large constant. Something like $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(1+y^2-z^2)=0$.
$$u_x=\frac{1}{1+x+y^2-z^2}(1)$$ (using chain rule).
$$u_y=\frac{1}{1+x+y^2-z^2}(2y)$$
$$u_z=\frac{1}{1+x+y^2-z^2}(-2z)$$
$$u_{x}(1)+u_{y}(1)+u_{z}(1)=\frac{1}{2}(1+2-2)=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}}$$.

Comment: The answer in my nook is 1.25..